# Disabling secure boot no longer loads ubuntu gnome (UEFI)

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, gnome, uefi, ubuntu-gnome

I have installed ubuntu gnome next to windows 10 on an acer a7 with UEFI.
 I'm trying to install a nvidia driver and for that I need to disable secure boot.
When I turn off secure boot, I reach a terminal instead of the ubuntu login screen. Why is that?

[image]

Comment: Does Ubuntu boot if you enable Secure boot again ?

Comment: No it does not. So it must be one of the numerous drivers I've tried which I shall have to remove again. Sigh